# After using np.poly1d() in matplotlib plot double entry in the legend

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a plot with a regression line and so far managed to do this as following:

```
plot1 = plot(data_plot.year, data_plot.Column1, color='red', label='plot1')
fit = np.polyfit(data_plot.year,data_plot.Column1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit) 
ost_reg = plot(data_plot.year, data_plot.Column1, '', data_plot.year,
               fit_fn(data_plot.year), color='red', linewidth=1,
               linestyle='dashed', label=' linear')

legend(loc = 'upper left')
```

But in the legend the 'linear' line occurs twice. Why?

**Plot example**

[image]

Comment: you may want to give us a self-contained code example. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You plot two lines with the same label.

This prints two lines, one with and one without label:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(data_plot.year, data_plot.Column1, '', 
        color='red', linewidth=1, 
        linestyle='dashed',  label=' linear')
ax.plot(data_plot.year,  fit_fn(data_plot.year), color='red', linewidth=1, 
        linestyle='dashed')
```

There should be only one entry in the legend for both.